# Trying to connect to server using Socket.IO on Android receives 400 error xhr poll error

Tags: android, node.js, kotlin, socket.io

I am receiving an error just trying to set up an initial connection between the android client and my local socket server running Node.js but keep getting this xhr poll error, I have been trying to resolve this for the past few hours but not having much luck, any help would be appreciated. I have added the correct perms to the manifest and also made sure to use the private IP of the server (local machine), I can browse / telnet to this port, I have tried this on both the emulator and Physical device but receive the same error.

**Client Connection**

```
@Synchronized
fun setSocket() {
    try {
Log.d("socketHandler", "setting Socket" )
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.156:3000")

        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR){
            Log.d("SocketHandler" ,"Connection Error : ${it}")
            it.forEach { item ->
                val exception = item as EngineIOException
                print(exception.message + " " + exception.code + " " + exception.cause)
            }
        }
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT){
            Log.d("SocketHandler", "TimeOut Error : $it")
        }
        establishConnection()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        when(e){
           is  URISyntaxException -> e.printStackTrace()
           is  EngineIOException -> {
               Log.d("EngineException", "${e.code}, ${e.transport}, ${e.message}")
               e.printStackTrace()
           }
            else -> e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
}
```

**Mainifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AirHockeyCompose">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AirHockeyCompose.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Server**

```
    const { Server } = require("socket.io");
    
    const io = new Server({ /* options */ });
    
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("connection")
      console.log(socket)
    });

io.listen(3000);
```

**Error (this is received in Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR)**

```
xhr poll error null java.io.IOException: 400io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on this but I did it some time back in a task. What I had was a nodejs server containing some images and an android that connects to it through socket to display them.

The connection was going fine I had no errors on it and you are free to check them here if it helps you in anyway https://github.com/aliosman21/Minly-Task .

As for your given snippets the only thing I noticed is that the server IP on emulators should be 10.0.2.2 (if memory serves) but since you already tried it on physical device I am not so sure.

I believe we both used the same client library https://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/initialization.html

Another thing to make sure about is if you are using a self signed certificate on the server you have to pass `{rejectUnauthorized: false}` in the options